# Cancelling the collect of the Kotlin flow

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I have a parent class that has different states, this parent class has a list of child classes that have different states each. I want to collect on each one of them and cancel the one that reaches the `Terminated` state. Something like that:

```
coroutineScope.launch(Dispatcher.IO) {
   parent.parentState.collect {
      if(it is ParentState.Normal){
         it.children.forEach{ child ->
             coroutineScope.launch(Dispatcher.IO){
                child.childState.collect{
                    if(it is ChildState.Terminated){
                       //when this line executed all the collectors stop until I change the states for each one of them..
                       this.coroutineContext.job.cancel()
                    } else{
                       // Do something else for any other state...
                    }
                }
             }

         }
      }
   }
}
```

But when I do that all the children that I am collecting from stop collecting, but it starts collecting again If I changed the state for each one of them, which is wasn't the case before cancelling one of them.

So my question is why it behaves like that when cancelling the job for one of the collectors?

Also is there a better way "reactive way" to write this?

Comment: What do you mean by `all the collectors stop` in your code snippet? There is only one collector for that flow. You want to cancel collection of the child which reaches terminated state while flow of other children should continue, is this what you want?

Comment: Exactly. The other children should continue.

Answer (score 0):

By default, coroutine scope is using `Job()` in `CoroutineContext`, `Job()` will cancel coroutine execution or any running child on canceled or exception thrown.

To keep other child execution remain active, you can use special `Job`, which is `SupervisorJob()`

```
CoroutineScope(SupervisorJob() + Dispatchers.IO)
```

Also, let's create a brand new scope for each child

```
val childScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)
childScope.launch {
    child.childState.collect {
        ....
    }
}
```

and you should cancel those `childScope` instead the `coroutineContext`.

Therefore, your code will looks like below

```
val scope = CoroutineScope(SupervisorJob() + Dispatchers.IO)
scope.launch {
   parent.parentState.collect {
      if(it is ParentState.Normal){
         it.children.forEach{ child ->
             val childScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)
             childScope.launch(Dispatcher.IO){
                child.childState.collect{
                    if(it is ChildState.Terminated){
                       //when this line executed all the collectors stop until I change the states for each one of them..
                       childScope.cancel()
                    } else{
                       // Do something else for any other state...
                    }
                }
             }

         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this will work. Why do you add the supervisor job in the parent scope?

Comment: I tried your approach but I still have the same problem, which all the children stop until I change the state of the children.

Comment: Is there any other parent scope launch this coroutine?

Comment: No. I tried a lot of things but nothing works for me, I am really confused.

Comment: How about using new scope for each child, lemme update the answer

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree that you can use `SupervisorJob` to deal with your problems.

But in my opinion, not so many sub-jobs are needed. A sub-job can solve the problems you encounter. In your code, a child coroutine of the size of `children Collection` will be created. Although the coroutine is very lightweight, I think it is unnecessary overhead.

You can completely convert `List<Flow<T>>` into `Flow<List<T>>` before each `Flow` `collect`. After that, only the converted single `Flow` can be `collect`.

Here is how I handled it:

```kotlin
inline fun <reified T> List<Flow<T>>.flattenFlow(): Flow<List<T>> = combine(this@flattenFlow) {
    it.toList()
}

coroutineScope.launch(Dispatcher.IO) {
    parent.parentState.collect {
        if (it is ParentState.Normal) {
            it.flattenFlow().collect {childStateList ->
                childStateList.onEach {childState ->
                    if (childState is ChildState.Terminated) {
                        // Do something when state in Terminated..
                    } else {
                        // Do something else for any other state...
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```